# How to add highlight to php tags in netbeans (all area between)

Tags: php, netbeans, highlight

In Netbeans I would like to have a background color for all the area between (and including) the php opening and closing tag. From `<?php` all the way to `?>`.
Not only highlighting the tags themself. Is this possible?
In pimcore it would help me to easily distinguish between html-portions and php-portions within view-templates.

Edit:
What i would likt to have is some similar highlighting we have with Smarty for the php code:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/File:SmartySyntax.png

Comment: you mean?......

Comment: It's for the view in Pimcore. Pimcore uses the Zend-framework. So the view is the template file mixing html code with php code (so very normal php code). The code would be much easier to read in Netbeans if blocks of php code would be highlighted with a different background color. Is this possible to achieve in Netbeans?

Comment: I can tell you from my own expericence as I stated in my edit: this is not pimcore related. This Problem occures everywhere when no explicit templating language exists.

WordPress, Drupal, Processwire, you name it. 

Maybe a change of IDE is a good idea, I suggest PhpStorm.

Comment: Just a small question: Which netbeans version are you using?

Comment: I am using Netbeans 8.2.
As i said i would like to have a background color for the whole php-segments or html-segments to make it easy to differentiate them visually.
I don't see how the link you gave me could help me in this regard.

Comment: Sorry, I have overread that.